# SSRS mutilple value that checks if sql db column is null

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I have a nullable datetime2 column. The column contains the most recent login date. If the column is null, the user has not logged in.

I have a SSRS report that filters whether a user has logged in or not. If column is null, then user has not logged in. I have a parameter that takes multiple values(all,logged in, not logged in) that I pass to a stored proc. Currently I have set the values to Logged in = 1 and not logged in = 2.

My storedproc receives the value as @HasLoggedIn varchar(50).

How would I go about selecting either (all,logged in, not logged in) in sql.

Is there a better way to set this up in ssrs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit lost at passing the parameter, but basically I think you're looking for this:

```
DECLARE
  @loginOption int = 0

SELECT 
  [UserID],
  [Timestamp]
FROM [Logins]
WHERE 
  (CASE
     WHEN @loginOption = 0 THEN 1 -- ALL
     WHEN @loginOption = 1 AND [Timestamp] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 -- Logged in
     WHEN @loginOption = 2 AND [Timestamp] IS NULL THEN 1 -- Not logged in
     ELSE 0
   END) = 1
```

And here is a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5358d/4) for it.

Comment: I was using text to pass the parameter, but I changed it to int and added all = 3. Thanx works great